# SQL Query make 'groups' with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently selecting all streams that are given saved for 1 episode.
My problem is: I only want 1 stream per episode to be selected.
I first wanted to save the episode-number with all the other data in an array and delete the doubled entrys. Means: If there would be 2 entrys with the same episode-number, delete one.

However I think the better solution would be to make this with an sql query.. I don't know, maybe it's the worse option.

My question now is: How do I make a SQL Query, which gives me only 1 result for each episode-number and language?

Maybe the screenshot helps a little bit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include additional criteria for which episode you want to keep. Here's an example that keeps the first-uploaded record (assuming upload dates are precise enough to be unique):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (
   select epi_nr, MIN(upload_date) As upload_date
    from Spalte
    group by epi_nr
 ) g
INNER JOIN Spalte s on s.epi_nr = g.epi_nr AND s.upload_date = g.upload_date
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. It works but not the way I exactly want. Because now it shows 1 result per episode, but it should also group for every language and type.

Comment: Ohh okay, just by adding the fields on "group by" it works. Thanks a lot for your answer!